# Adding an attachment to existing PDF file using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I have a Stream of a PDF file and would like to add a excel or text file attachment in the PDF. 
The following code does the job but it essentially copies the existing PDF page by page to a new one and adds the attachments. I have to copy page by page because PdfWriter can not open an existing PDF say from PdfReader. Is there a better way of doing this? I played around with PdfStamper as well but looks like no matter what you need PdfWriter to attach the file.

The code is a Action method from ASP.Net MVC app.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        string s = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/temp/");

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file.InputStream);
        Document document = new Document();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
        document.Open();
        document.AddDocListener(writer);

        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            document.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSize(i));
            document.NewPage();
            PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
            PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
            int rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(i);
            if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270)
                cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1.0F, 1.0F, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Height);
            else
                cb.AddTemplate(page, 1.0F, 0, 0, 1.0F, 0, 0);
        }

        PdfFileSpecification pfs = PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded(writer, s + "test.xlsx", "test.xlsx", null);
        writer.AddFileAttachment(pfs);

        document.Close();

        return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/pdf", "test.pdf");
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered using a PdfStamper?

Comment: Yes but even PdfStamper needs PdfWriter which gets me back to the same problem which is how to put an existing document into PdfWriter. In the Java examples I've seen stamper.getWriter() but that method is not available in the C# iTextSharp version (latest) I have.

Comment: First of all PdfStamper, while relying on a class derived from PdfWriter, does not require you to copy page by page, and it also doesn't do that under the hood.

Comment: Yes but the only way I know how to attach a file is to use PdfFileSpecification.FileEmbedded which requires PdfWriter. So guess my question would be how do I get PdfWriter out of PdfStamper?

Comment: Look for stamper.Writer - java getters oftentimes have such pendants.

Comment: Thanks mkl stamper.Writer helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are dozens of Java examples based on the [iText book](http://itextpdf.com/book) on the official iText website. These examples are also available in C# in the SVN repository. There are shortened links to these examples formatted like this: http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C07

In this case, the 07 points to the examples from Chapter 7. If you need chapter 8, replace 07 by 08.

Chapter 7 is the chapter you need to find out how to add annotations using `PdfStamper`. You indeed need a `PdfWriter` instance, and when comparing the Java examples with their C# port, you'll discover that the C# counter-part of `stamper.getWriter()` is `stamper.Writer`.